# Getting two different answers on same input just by different methods of initialization of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, dynamic-programming

I was solving a DP problem, Longest Increasing Subsequence, wherein I initialized the dp array by two different methods and got different results for the same input.

First method, where I got the wrong answer was: `int dp[n] = {1};`

Second method, again a wrong answer: `int dp[n];
                                      memset(dp, 1, sizeof(dp));`

Finally, when I initialized the array manually using a "for loop", I got the right answer.

**What is the difference between all the three methods of initialization ?**

**Input:** *First Line (N i.e size of the array), next line : array elements*

83

86 177 115 193 135 186 92 49 21 162 27 90 59 163 126 140 26 172 136 11 168 167 29 182 130 62 123 67 135 129 2 22 58 69 167 193 56 11 42 29 173 21 119 184 137 198 124 115 170 13 126 91 180 156 73 62 170 196 81 105 125 84 127 136 105 46 129 113 57 124 95 182 145 14 167 34 164 43 150 87 8 76 178

Correct output: 15

My answer with "memset" and direct initialization was 14. Got 15 after initializing using a for-loop.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis it's valid with Clang and GCC.

Comment: @Zoe but not with the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
int dp[n] = {1};
```

you initialize the *first* element to `1`, and the rest to zero.

With

```
memset(dp, 1, sizeof(dp));
```

you set all *bytes* to `1`, which means that each element in the array will be `0x01010101`.

The "correct" way to set all elements of an array to a specific value is to use the [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n). Or use a `std::vector` where you can pass a default value to the constructor for each element.